# is poor document-production support intentional?

Tags: pdf-format, document-creation

I recently endured substantial frustration trying to save a slide show as PDF (never achieving anything acceptible), but generally I have had decent luck with regular notebooks (even big ones).  Here, "decent luck" means "allowing for the inability to float figures and tables, the inability to interact with BibTeX databases to produce inline citations, etc".)  Now [Paul Romer claims Mma's limited PDF support must be intentional](https://paulromer.net/jupyter-mathematica-and-the-future-of-the-research-paper/) and describes his own reasons for believing this.  The idea seems to be that Wolfram does know how to use Mma to produce good looking PDF documents (see NKS, for example) but is refusing to share that knowledge in order to promote its proprietary CDF format.  My own view is that there is no conspiracy of silence; rather Wolfram has sadly limited interest in supporting the production of beautiful printed documents (except his own, as NKS evinces).  Romer's "evidence" is too impressionistic -- it seems more of a lashing out in frustration.  Is there any real evidence for his view (or mine)?  And as a related question, is there any active Wolfram project to turn Mma into a more serious academic authoring tool?

Comment: Interesting thing to discuss for sure, but I think it is off-topic. Please make the post more specific with a list of concrete evidence or a list of frustrations. (Even rudimentary lists would be good.)

Comment: @Nasser Do you have a workflow description you can share?

Comment: BTW, that article by Paul Romer is full of BS opinions.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I disagree that this question merely solicits opinion.  It ends with: " Is there any real evidence for his view (or mine)? And as a related question, is there any active Wolfram project to turn Mma into a more serious academic authoring tool?"
As for turning slides into PDFs: try it.  Everything I tried was disaster: the PDF looked NOTHING like the slides: wrong font sizes, wrong page breaks, inability to choose a plausible page size, etc.  If you come up with a good way please post it.  Until then, please consider this a concrete complaint, which I'm not the first to offer.

Comment: @Nasser While that PDF is pretty nice looking, despite the page overflows, it lacks many crucial components of academic writing (including those listed in my post).

Comment: @Alan I still have not seen anything concrete from you. The questions in your comment -- *"Is there any real evidence for his view (or mine)? And as a related question, is there any active Wolfram project to turn Mma into a more serious academic authoring tool?"* --  are better suited to be on community.wolfram.com or MathematicaMeta. Can you share the notebook which you cannot convert to a good PDF slideshow?

Comment: @AntonAntonov I would gladly accept from you *any* sldeshow + a successful process for converting it.  I consider that pretty concrete: this is not specific to one file.  [Others have noted the problem.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/520951)

Comment: There is new tool [announcing-wolfram-presenter-tools](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/04/17/announcing-wolfram-presenter-tools/) may be this will work for you.

Comment: @Nasser I'm not seeing anything new here in terms of producing PDFs from slide shows.  Let me know if I'm wrong.